# How to evaluate the K-Modes Clusters?

Tags: python, clustering, k-means, distance

K-modes algorithm is available [here](https://pypi.org/project/kmodes/)

I want to do clustering of my binary dataset. I need to specify the number of clusters that I need as an output:

```
KModes (n_clusters, init, n_init, verbose)
```

My dataset contains 1000 lines and 1000 rows, I want to calculate the distance between my clusters in order to know the exact number of cluster that I need to choose. I don't know how to compare between them. Probably I want to use the hamming distance because it is the most suitable distance to compare between binary data.

Any recommendations that you can give are welcomed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The are some techniques to choose the number of clusters `K`.

The most common ones are **The Elbow Method** and **The Silhouette Method.**

## Elbow Method

In this method, you calculate a score function with different values for `K`. You can use the Hamming distance like you proposed, or other scores, like dispersion.

Then, you plot them and where the function creates "an elbow" you choose the value for `K`.

[image]

## Silhouette Method

[This method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html) measure the distance from points in one cluster to the other clusters. Then visually you have silhouette plots that let you choose `K`.

Observe:

`K=2`, silhouette of similar heights but with different sizes. So, potential candidate.
[image]

`K=3`, silhouettes of different heights. So, bad candidate.
[image]

`K=4`, silhouette of similar heights and sizes. Best candidate.
[image]

Comment: very thorough answer!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: So the same techniques that apply to Kmeans, also work on Kmodes?

Comment: @CarlosMougan yes

Comment: good coverage of a common issue!

Comment: silhouettes plot is distance based - works on k means not k modes though？

Answer (score 0):

The KMeans algo is pretty slick, but it's a bit primitive compared to other algos out there.  If you are interested in having a clustering algo automatically figure out the number of clusters for you, so you don't have to, you can use `Affinity Propagation`.

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# #############################################################################
# Generate sample data
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
#%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import datasets#Iris Dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data

# #############################################################################
# Compute Affinity Propagation
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-50).fit(X)
cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_

n_clusters_ = len(cluster_centers_indices)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)


# #############################################################################
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

plt.close('all')
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

colors = cycle('bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk')
for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters_), colors):
    class_members = labels == k
    cluster_center = X[cluster_centers_indices[k]]
    plt.plot(X[class_members, 0], X[class_members, 1], col + '.')
    plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
    for x in X[class_members]:
        plt.plot([cluster_center[0], x[0]], [cluster_center[1], x[1]], col)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

Output: `Estimated number of clusters: 3`

[image]

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-affinity-propagation-py

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: are you going to say how any of this relates to kmodes?